# Не получается изменить __proto__ у Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

В MDN [говорится](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> Обратите внимание, что свойство `__proto__` может быть переопределено даже у объекта `Object.prototype`, если новая цепочка заканчивается `null`

Однако, при попытке выполнить код из примера

```js
var b = {};

Object.prototype.__proto__ =
  Object.create(null, // [[Prototype]]
                { hi: { value: function() { alert('hi'); } } });

b.hi();
```

я получаю ошибку в хроме (версия 63.0.3239.132 x64)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Immutable prototype object '#<Object>' cannot have their prototype set
    at Object.set __proto__ [as __proto__] (<anonymous>)
    at js:15
```

и в Firefox'е (версия 58.0 x64)

```
TypeError: can't set prototype of this object
```

А вот в IE11 всё работает.

Почему так происходит и можно ли всё-таки изменить этот прототип?

Comment: на en задай тоже :)

Comment: ассоциация: [The builtin prototype object Object.prototype is now an Immutable Prototype Exotic Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41076789/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, ну давай ассоциацию и ответ. Желательно поподробнее, потому что я не понял, в чём заключается опасность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последняя на данный момент спецификация говорит, что

> The Object prototype object is the intrinsic object %ObjectPrototype%. The Object prototype object is an **immutable prototype exotic object**.

---

Это нововведение ES7 (aka ES2016). Встроенный прототип объекта `Object.prototype` на данный момент [Immutable Prototype Exotic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-immutable-prototype-exotic-objects) у которого внутренний слот `[[prototype]]` заблокирован.

Предполагается, что это [предотвратит вставку посредника в глобальный механизм поиска](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/272), см. [этот коммит](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commit/935dad4283d045bc09c67a259279772d01b3d33d) для более детальной информации. [Это реализовано в V8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5149).

<sub>[перевод ответа @Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41076789/2881286)</sub>

---

Небольшое пояснение можно найти по [ссылкам из issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399951). В примере

```
<!-- ************** http://victim/test.csv ************** -->
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"');
?>
foo,bar,123

<!-- ************** http://attacker/ ************** -->
<script>
window.__proto__ = Proxy.create({
    get: function(target, name) {console.log("data=" + name)}
});
</script>
<script src="http://victim/test.csv"></script>
```

---

В этом примере был вывод: "data=foo" и "data=bar". Позволило бы изменить текущей странице значения используемые в загружаемом скрипте.

Comment: Вообще-то я не понял, как чего можно украсть и почему глобальный прокси - это опасно. Хотелось бы больше деталей на эту тему.

Comment: @Qwertiy, по сути не украсть, а повлиять на работу стороннего скрипта. В примере используются глобальные переменные. которые можно подменять и т.д. если подменить прототип у Object, тогда можно менять все  у всех объектов. Важно при этом, что скрипт может быть загружен с другого домена

Comment: Но ведь я и без прокси могу поменять глобальные переменные... Они же _глобальные!_

Comment: @Qwertiy, не совсем так. Если эти переменные инициализируются внутри скрипта - то твои изменения ничего не дадут.

Comment: Да ладно? https://jsfiddle.net/xjzdgest/9/

Comment: @Qwertiy, логично :-) с другой стороны в прокси ты не завязан на имя переменной

Comment: Т. е. прокси помогает в универсальности атаки? Но ведь в если я даже имя не знаю, то я и понятия не имею, как эта переменная используется и что с ней делать. В чём польза?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73170/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).